# Finding $ \lim_{x\to -2}~~ \sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})\frac{x^2+1}{x+2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would really appreciate if you could help me solving this limit problem!

Find the limit without using L'Hopital's rule!

$$ \lim_{x\to -2} \sin\bigg(\frac{\pi x}{2}\bigg)\frac{x^2+1}{x+2} = ?$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To make it clearer, do you really mean $\frac{x^2+1}{x+2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$? Then It is easy, the $x^2+1$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, pull out $\lim_{x\to -2} (x^2+1)$ from the limit.  Then, set $y=x+2$, which gives
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin \big((\frac{\pi}{2}y)-(\frac{\pi}{2}2)\big)}{y}=$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}y)}{y}=$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}y)}{\frac{\pi}{2}y}=$$

$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{\frac{\pi}{2}y\to 0}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}y)}{\frac{\pi}{2}y}=$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now combine with the $5$ you pulled out previously to get $-\frac{5\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: Use $\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi(x+2)}{2}\right)}{\frac{\pi(x+2)}{2}} \to 1$ as $x \to -2$

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned in the question that I am looking for a solution that does not use L'Hopital.

Comment: Thanks again, to tell the truth I am looking for a solution that avoid Tailor expansion as well but using more basic techniques.